# php mail and apache server how to remove apache from the from field

Tags: web-services, apache2, plesk

i am using a php mail script to send mail, but when sent the user is getting Apache server has the from. How to remove apache server from the from header of a email.

```
<?php
//mail script
$to = 'email@email.com';
$subject = "Your welcome";
$header= "From: admin";
//other headers
$server = "email.com";
ini_set("SMTP, $server");

$message = "hello";

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

i have tried removing $server and ini_set line. when i do this i get domainname@servername.com.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the examples in the PHP manual, specifically [example 4](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php#example-3189) on the `mail` page.

There are two issues in your script:

1. You're setting the `$header` variable, then using `$headers` in the `mail` function call.
2. The from header must contain an actual email address, and may optionally contain a name

It should be

```
$headers = 'From: Admin <admin@example.com>';
```

That will show the name Admin and have the email admin@example.com.